# Включение видео по нажатию на текст

Tags: html, css, iframe

У меня есть текст под видео, мне нужно чтобы видео включалось не только по нажатию на него но и по нажатию на текст. Как это реализовать? Вот код:

css:

```
 .video-box {
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden; }

.video-box p:hover {    
    color: #5FA467;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="video-box">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GKSRyLdjsPA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
    <p>Some textSome textSome textSome textSome text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ru

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, но тут нет нужной мне информации

Comment: https://webkab.ru/zapustit-video-youtube-po-kliku-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно реализовать через `jQuery`

К тексту(`p`) добавляем класс `class="click"`

И, вырезка из [статьи](https://webkab.ru/zapustit-video-youtube-po-kliku-jquery/)
`Теперь внимание! Нам нужно в конце ссылки добавить параметры ?rel=0&showinfo=0 - чтобы не было инфы перед запуском и чтобы не воспроизводились другие после завершения. Если вы не хотите этого добавлять, то добавьте хотя бы знак вопроса в конце, потому что иначе работать оно не будет.`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".click").click(function() {
    var $video = $(this).parent().find('iframe:first'),
      src = $video.attr('src');
    $video.attr('src', src + '&autoplay=1');
    console.log($video);
  });

});
```

```css
.video-box {
  width: 210px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-box p:hover {
  color: #5FA467;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-box">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GKSRyLdjsPA?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
  <p class="click">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome text</p>
</div>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ejapyh4/1/)

Comment: низкий поклон Вам! только у меня вопрос к вам. у меня этих видео с текстом много. как для всех сделать? а то он только для одного работает?

Comment: @AsasSas Подправил ответ

Comment: спfсибо!!!!!!!asdasd